# Apply class to two elements depending on PHP condition

Tags: php, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I create various div.form-groups using PHP and based on data from backend. Like so:

```
<div class="row">
 <?php foreach($fields as $r){ ?>
  <div class="form-group col-md-6 <?php if($r->description) echo 'desc-fix' ?>">
        <label class="label-heading"><?php echo $r->title ?></label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="field_id_<?=$r->ID?>">
        <span class="help-block"><?=$r->description?></span>
  </div>
 <?php } ?>
</div>
```

Normally it would look like this

[image]

Some fields have a description, and some don't. For those that do have, I want to apply min-height:140px which I do with class desc-fix. The problem is, the div.form-group below div.desc-fix switches places. As you can see below, one of the fields switched columns.

[image]

As a fix, I changed desc-fix to be like this

```
.desc-fix + div { min-height: 140px; }
```

This makes it so the next div will also have min-height:140px, but if the div.desc-fix is on the right hand column, the element at the bottom left will also have min-height:140px. So obviously this doesn't fix anything.

**Basically I want to apply min-height:140px to fields that match this criteria:**

- Has description
- Element in the same row should always have min-height:140px too
- Elements in the next row must not be affected

I don't know how to apply this rules though